# Mongo aggregate pipeline stops filtering after 2 operators. Using meteorhacks aggregate

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I am using Meteor with the meteorhacks:aggregate package. I am trying to pull out the birthdays that match today's date.

```
var today = new Date();

  result = ContactList.aggregate(
    {
      $project: {
        name: 1,
        birthday:1,
        todayDayOfYear:{"$dayOfYear":today},
        dayOfYear:{"$dayOfYear":"$birthday"},

      }
    }, 
    {
      $project: {
        name:1,
        birthday:1,
        dayDifference:{"$subtract":["$dayOfYear","$todayDayOfYear"]}
      }
    },
    {
      $match:{
        dayDifference:0
      }
    }

  );

  console.log(result);
```

The aggregation seems to stop after the second $project.The code outputs all the entries even though I have used $match.

```
I20160107-09:19:04.314(8)? [ { _id: 'e4cK95xh453kamAw2',
I20160107-09:19:04.315(8)?     name: 'Today',
I20160107-09:19:04.315(8)?     birthday: Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00        GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.315(8)?     dayDifference: 358 },
I20160107-09:19:04.315(8)?   { _id: 'z93CfgwbHvHPurYxe',
I20160107-09:19:04.315(8)?     name: 'hello',
I20160107-09:19:04.315(8)?     birthday: Sat Jan 02 2016 00:00:00      GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.316(8)?     dayDifference: -6 },
I20160107-09:19:04.316(8)?   { _id: 'YkrjyFNp6Ei28qrrH',
I20160107-09:19:04.316(8)?     name: 'yoyo',
I20160107-09:19:04.316(8)?     birthday: Sun Jan 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.316(8)?     dayDifference: -5 },
I20160107-09:19:04.316(8)?   { _id: 'i2idScCcsKjimiPYW',
I20160107-09:19:04.317(8)?     name: 'yolo',
I20160107-09:19:04.317(8)?     birthday: Mon Jan 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.317(8)?     dayDifference: -4 },
I20160107-09:19:04.317(8)?   { _id: 'mSBHiFigA8h7egs6J',
I20160107-09:19:04.317(8)?     name: 'yesterday',
I20160107-09:19:04.318(8)?     birthday: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.318(8)?     dayDifference: -3 },
I20160107-09:19:04.318(8)?   { _id: 'CnZqpnd9d6K66R8GL',
I20160107-09:19:04.318(8)?     name: 'today',
I20160107-09:19:04.318(8)?     birthday: Wed Jan 06 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.319(8)?     dayDifference: -2 },
I20160107-09:19:04.319(8)?   { _id: 'RxuczFihgEjQQtA2E',
I20160107-09:19:04.319(8)?     name: 'tomorrow',
I20160107-09:19:04.319(8)?     birthday: Thu Jan 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.319(8)?     dayDifference: -1 },
I20160107-09:19:04.319(8)?   { _id: 'EBgdyPSpXDkgBd7Y7',
I20160107-09:19:04.320(8)?     name: 'day after tomorrow',
I20160107-09:19:04.320(8)?     birthday: Fri Jan 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT),
I20160107-09:19:04.320(8)?     dayDifference: 0 } ]
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does it work properly for you when running same pipeline on mongodb shell?

Comment: try to wrap your pipepline in an array [], aggregate should take an array of pipeline stage, not object like in your code

Comment: @somallg your solution worked! I just wrapped it in []. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
today: function() {
   Contactlist.find({"birthday":{ $gt: new Date()}});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this gives me an undefined.

Comment: It doesn't give the undefined after I corrected the Collection name. It returns the following: { collectionName: 'contacts',
I20160109-11:31:26.588(8)?      selector: { birthday: [Object] },
I20160109-11:31:26.588(8)?      options: { transform: null } },
I20160109-11:31:26.588(8)?   _synchronousCursor: null }